# Fetching data from different table in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have two tables that generates an messageboard output. The first table uses a while loop to show all answers in a given topic from table **posts**. This works fine.

Then I have aniother table named **thumbsup** which collects when a user hits the "thumbs up" icon to a post in the messageboard. I only want the spesific user to be able to press the "thumbs up" button once.

I am trying to fetch data from table **thumbsup** to determine if the user has pressed the button or not for each post in the **posts** table.

I have tried the following sql statement:

```
SELECT topic, user FROM thumbsup WHERE topic = ".$posts_row['id']." AND user = ".$_SESSION['username']."
```

the table **thumbsup** looks like this:

```
id | topic | user
1  | 1     | bill
2  | 3     | rachel
3  | 5     | bill
4  | 5     | rachel
5  | 7     | rachel
```

my problem here is that I can't get the sql to sort by both topic and username. I can get it to sort by topic, but then it only outputs the first entry for the given post; in this case it would output "bill" on post number 5.

I think I maybe need a new while loop inside the existing while loop, but I haven't got that to work either.

Help much appreciated!

EDIT:

Ok, so I have this query to fetch the posts, AND to check if the user has a thumbsup record:

`"SELECT posts.topic, posts.id, posts.content, posts.date, posts.user, posts.moderation, thumbsup.topic, thumbsup.user FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN thumbsup ON posts.id = thumbsup.topic AND thumbsup.user = ".$_SESSION['username']." WHERE posts.topic = " . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).""`

- This results in none posts in the while loop, but if I remove the username, it shows only the posts again. Is there something wrong in my query?

EDIT2 - SOLUTION:

I finally got it right, much thanks to [Kickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723545/kickstart).

Here is my final sql query:

```
SELECT posts.topic, posts.id, posts.content, posts.date, (posts.user) AS users, posts.moderation, thumbsup.topic, thumbsup.user FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN thumbsup ON posts.id = AA_forum_thumbsup.topic AND thumbsup.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' WHERE posts.topic = " . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."
```

As Kickstart mentioned, I needed extra quotes around the username as it is a string, and I also had to define the useres from the posts table as "users". Else the result would only output data on the posts where the username like $_SESSION['username'].

Thank you very much, and I hope this is useful for others as well!

Comment: what you actually want? couldn't understand give an example. what you want for topic no 5

Comment: it would output the first thumbsup of `username` on a certain `topic`. You don't need a while loop if you want to know only if this person clicked thumbs up on that post

Comment: join the two tables and use sort in your query (sort multiple columns with comma separated)

Comment: Actually what is the output you wanted ...?

Comment: I want to be able to determine if the user has already voted for the post or not. If the user has voted, then he will not be able to vote for that spesific post again. Just like a forum "thumbs up" or Facebooks "Like" button.

Comment: As @ViswanathPolaki suggests, do a JOIN in the original query. Seems you are only interested in the current user, so use a LEFT JOIN from the topics table to the thumbsup table, specifying the user in the ON clause of the join. This way you will get the topic with the vote if there has been one, but if not vote you just get the topic.

Comment: If I do a LEFT JOIN specifying the username, wouldn't it only show that specific users posts as well, and not the other users posts? Please draw an example of this example knowing that the TOPIC row in THUMBSUP table is linked to the post-id in the POSTS table.

Comment: Not if you put the check of the user id in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN. In this case it would only join comments for that user, but the posts would be limited by the WHERE clause rather than the ON clause.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your query that would stop it working. Might be worth setting up an example on SQLfiddle so we can check it. One point is that you are using real escape string on the id field, which I assume is an integer ID. This would leave you open to an SQL injection attack. Better to just use intval or the like to force it to an int.

Comment: SQLfiddle seems to be down, any other site similar? By the way, the query outputs error "Unknown column 'testuser' in 'on clause'". Any ideas?

Comment: You need extra quote around the username on the join (as it is a string). You probably should escape it as well unless you have stored it as an escaped version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a LEFT JOIN, something like this:-

```
SELECT posts.id, thumbsup.user 
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN thumbsup 
ON posts.id = thumbsup.topic
AND thumbsup.user = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
```

This will bring back all the posts (in this case just the ids of them) and user field will contain the username if $_SESSION['username'] has a thumbsup record for this post. If they don't then the user field returned will be NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think you are login to your application,if yes then only take record for login user and then sort it by topic. now u will get array with values as topic.Here you can check using inarray() .If the value is persent in inarray then it means the user had already voted.